# corr.test arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r

I have seen this error multiple times in different projects and I was wondering if there is a way to tell which line caused the error **in general**?

My specific case:

```
 http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00275/

#using the bike.csv
data<-read.csv("PATH_HERE\\Bike-Sharing-Dataset\\day.csv",header=TRUE)
require(psych)
corr.test(data) 
data<-data[,c("atemp","casual","cnt","holiday","hum","mnth","registered",
              "season","temp","weathersit","weekday","windspeed","workingday","yr")]
data[data=='']<-NA
#View(data)

require(psych)
cors<-corr.test(data)
```

returns the error:

```
Error in data.frame(lower = lower, r = r[lower.tri(r)], upper = upper,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 91
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
> #using the bike.csv
> data <- read.csv("day.csv",header=TRUE)
> require(psych)
> corr.test(data) 
Error in cor(x, use = use, method = method) : 'x' must be numeric
> data <- data[,c("atemp","casual","cnt","holiday","hum","mnth","registered",
+               "season","temp","weathersit","weekday","windspeed","workingday","yr")]
> data[data==''] <- NA
> #View(data)
> 
> require(psych)
> cors <- corr.test(data)
> cors
Call:corr.test(x = data)
Correlation matrix 
           atemp casual   cnt holiday   hum  mnth registered season  temp
atemp       1.00   0.54  0.63   -0.03  0.14  0.23       0.54   0.34  0.99
casual      0.54   1.00  0.67    0.05 -0.08  0.12       0.40   0.21  0.54
cnt         0.63   0.67  1.00   -0.07 -0.10  0.28       0.95   0.41  0.63
holiday    -0.03   0.05 -0.07    1.00 -0.02  0.02      -0.11  -0.01 -0.03
hum         0.14  -0.08 -0.10   -0.02  1.00  0.22      -0.09   0.21  0.13
mnth        0.23   0.12  0.28    0.02  0.22  1.00       0.29   0.83  0.22
registered  0.54   0.40  0.95   -0.11 -0.09  0.29       1.00   0.41  0.54
season      0.34   0.21  0.41   -0.01  0.21  0.83       0.41   1.00  0.33
temp        0.99   0.54  0.63   -0.03  0.13  0.22       0.54   0.33  1.00
weathersit -0.12  -0.25 -0.30   -0.03  0.59  0.04      -0.26   0.02 -0.12
weekday    -0.01   0.06  0.07   -0.10 -0.05  0.01       0.06   0.00  0.00
windspeed  -0.18  -0.17 -0.23    0.01 -0.25 -0.21      -0.22  -0.23 -0.16
workingday  0.05  -0.52  0.06   -0.25  0.02 -0.01       0.30   0.01  0.05
yr          0.05   0.25  0.57    0.01 -0.11  0.00       0.59   0.00  0.05
           weathersit weekday windspeed workingday    yr
atemp           -0.12   -0.01     -0.18       0.05  0.05
casual          -0.25    0.06     -0.17      -0.52  0.25
cnt             -0.30    0.07     -0.23       0.06  0.57
holiday         -0.03   -0.10      0.01      -0.25  0.01
hum              0.59   -0.05     -0.25       0.02 -0.11
mnth             0.04    0.01     -0.21      -0.01  0.00
registered      -0.26    0.06     -0.22       0.30  0.59
season           0.02    0.00     -0.23       0.01  0.00
temp            -0.12    0.00     -0.16       0.05  0.05
weathersit       1.00    0.03      0.04       0.06 -0.05
weekday          0.03    1.00      0.01       0.04 -0.01
windspeed        0.04    0.01      1.00      -0.02 -0.01
workingday       0.06    0.04     -0.02       1.00  0.00
yr              -0.05   -0.01     -0.01       0.00  1.00
Sample Size 
[1] 731
Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
           atemp casual  cnt holiday  hum mnth registered season temp
atemp       0.00   0.00 0.00    1.00 0.01 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00
casual      0.00   0.00 0.00    1.00 1.00 0.04       0.00   0.00 0.00
cnt         0.00   0.00 0.00    1.00 0.28 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00
holiday     0.38   0.14 0.06    0.00 1.00 1.00       0.15   1.00 1.00
hum         0.00   0.04 0.01    0.67 0.00 0.00       0.58   0.00 0.03
mnth        0.00   0.00 0.00    0.60 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00
registered  0.00   0.00 0.00    0.00 0.01 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00
season      0.00   0.00 0.00    0.78 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00
temp        0.00   0.00 0.00    0.44 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00
weathersit  0.00   0.00 0.00    0.35 0.00 0.24       0.00   0.60 0.00
weekday     0.84   0.11 0.07    0.01 0.16 0.80       0.12   0.93 1.00
windspeed   0.00   0.00 0.00    0.87 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00
workingday  0.16   0.00 0.10    0.00 0.51 0.87       0.00   0.74 0.15
yr          0.21   0.00 0.00    0.83 0.00 0.96       0.00   0.96 0.20
           weathersit weekday windspeed workingday   yr
atemp            0.05    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
casual           0.00    1.00      0.00       0.00 0.00
cnt              0.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 0.00
holiday          1.00    0.25      1.00       0.00 1.00
hum              0.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 0.13
mnth             1.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
registered       0.00    1.00      0.00       0.00 0.00
season           1.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
temp             0.05    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
weathersit       0.00    1.00      1.00       1.00 1.00
weekday          0.40    0.00      1.00       1.00 1.00
windspeed        0.29    0.70      0.00       1.00 1.00
workingday       0.10    0.33      0.61       0.00 1.00
yr               0.19    0.88      0.75       0.96 0.00

 To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:::

```
rm(list=ls())
# http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00275/

#using the bike.csv

day <- read.csv("Bike-Sharing-Dataset//day.csv")

require(psych)

day<-day[,c("atemp","casual","cnt","holiday","hum","mnth","registered",
              "season","temp","weathersit","weekday","windspeed","workingday","yr")]

day[day=='']<-NA

require(psych)
corr.test(day) 


# corr.test(day)
# Call:corr.test(x = day)
# Correlation matrix 
# atemp casual   cnt holiday   hum  mnth registered season  temp weathersit weekday windspeed workingday    yr
# atemp       1.00   0.54  0.63   -0.03  0.14  0.23       0.54   0.34  0.99      -0.12   -0.01     -0.18       0.05  0.05
# casual      0.54   1.00  0.67    0.05 -0.08  0.12       0.40   0.21  0.54      -0.25    0.06     -0.17      -0.52  0.25
# cnt         0.63   0.67  1.00   -0.07 -0.10  0.28       0.95   0.41  0.63      -0.30    0.07     -0.23       0.06  0.57
# holiday    -0.03   0.05 -0.07    1.00 -0.02  0.02      -0.11  -0.01 -0.03      -0.03   -0.10      0.01      -0.25  0.01
# hum         0.14  -0.08 -0.10   -0.02  1.00  0.22      -0.09   0.21  0.13       0.59   -0.05     -0.25       0.02 -0.11
# mnth        0.23   0.12  0.28    0.02  0.22  1.00       0.29   0.83  0.22       0.04    0.01     -0.21      -0.01  0.00
# registered  0.54   0.40  0.95   -0.11 -0.09  0.29       1.00   0.41  0.54      -0.26    0.06     -0.22       0.30  0.59
# season      0.34   0.21  0.41   -0.01  0.21  0.83       0.41   1.00  0.33       0.02    0.00     -0.23       0.01  0.00
# temp        0.99   0.54  0.63   -0.03  0.13  0.22       0.54   0.33  1.00      -0.12    0.00     -0.16       0.05  0.05
# weathersit -0.12  -0.25 -0.30   -0.03  0.59  0.04      -0.26   0.02 -0.12       1.00    0.03      0.04       0.06 -0.05
# weekday    -0.01   0.06  0.07   -0.10 -0.05  0.01       0.06   0.00  0.00       0.03    1.00      0.01       0.04 -0.01
# windspeed  -0.18  -0.17 -0.23    0.01 -0.25 -0.21      -0.22  -0.23 -0.16       0.04    0.01      1.00      -0.02 -0.01
# workingday  0.05  -0.52  0.06   -0.25  0.02 -0.01       0.30   0.01  0.05       0.06    0.04     -0.02       1.00  0.00
# yr          0.05   0.25  0.57    0.01 -0.11  0.00       0.59   0.00  0.05      -0.05   -0.01     -0.01       0.00  1.00
# Sample Size 
# [1] 731
# Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
# atemp casual  cnt holiday  hum mnth registered season temp weathersit weekday windspeed workingday   yr
# atemp       0.00   0.00 0.00    1.00 0.01 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00       0.05    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
# casual      0.00   0.00 0.00    1.00 1.00 0.04       0.00   0.00 0.00       0.00    1.00      0.00       0.00 0.00
# cnt         0.00   0.00 0.00    1.00 0.28 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00       0.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 0.00
# holiday     0.38   0.14 0.06    0.00 1.00 1.00       0.15   1.00 1.00       1.00    0.25      1.00       0.00 1.00
# hum         0.00   0.04 0.01    0.67 0.00 0.00       0.58   0.00 0.03       0.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 0.13
# mnth        0.00   0.00 0.00    0.60 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00       1.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
# registered  0.00   0.00 0.00    0.00 0.01 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00       0.00    1.00      0.00       0.00 0.00
# season      0.00   0.00 0.00    0.78 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00       1.00    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
# temp        0.00   0.00 0.00    0.44 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00       0.05    1.00      0.00       1.00 1.00
# weathersit  0.00   0.00 0.00    0.35 0.00 0.24       0.00   0.60 0.00       0.00    1.00      1.00       1.00 1.00
# weekday     0.84   0.11 0.07    0.01 0.16 0.80       0.12   0.93 1.00       0.40    0.00      1.00       1.00 1.00
# windspeed   0.00   0.00 0.00    0.87 0.00 0.00       0.00   0.00 0.00       0.29    0.70      0.00       1.00 1.00
# workingday  0.16   0.00 0.10    0.00 0.51 0.87       0.00   0.74 0.15       0.10    0.33      0.61       0.00 1.00
# yr          0.21   0.00 0.00    0.83 0.00 0.96       0.00   0.96 0.20       0.19    0.88      0.75       0.96 0.00
# 
# To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
```

cheers